# Did Russia support both Georgian nationalists and the Georgian government during Georgian civil war?

Tags: 20th-century, russia, civil-war, post-communist-era

I am trying to understand the history of Georgia after the independence from Russia reading [the French Wikipedia article about it](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_de_la_G%C3%A9orgie#La_G%C3%A9orgie_post%E2%80%93sovi%C3%A9tique). Yet I don't understand the position of Russia during the Civil War.

> Plus tard dans l'année, les membres de l'opposition s'arment quand le commandant limogé de la Garde Nationale Tenguiz Kitovani rejoint le camp anti-Gamsakhourdia. À la fin du mois de décembre 1991, ils commencent le siège du Parlement, qui est pris le 6 janvier 1992, date du coup d'État qui amène l'exil du Président Gamsakhourdia chez ses voisins caucasiens. À ce moment, un Conseil d'État est formé et l'ancien chef du parti communiste géorgien Edouard Chevardnadzé est désigné comme chef du Conseil intérimaire.
>
> **Celui-ci poursuit la guerre en Ossétie du Sud et, au lieu d'atténuer les conflits séparatistes, envoie des troupes géorgiennes en Abkhazie pour réprimer les nationalistes qui virent vers la sécession à leur tour. Mais Tbilissi se heurte à une opposition armée et soutenue logistiquement par la Russie.** En un peu plus d'une année, la guerre est achevée et les séparatistes, après avoir déclaré à leur tour leur indépendance, se livrent à un nettoyage ethnique des Géorgiens présents sur leur territoire. **À la suite de cette défaite, Tbilissi tente de se rapprocher politiquement de la Russie qui s'accorde à lui envoyer une aide militaire pour combattre les nouveaux opposants menés par Gamsakhourdia** qui a établi un gouvernement en exil à Zougdidi.

Translated:

> *Later in the year, opposition members arm themselves when the dismissed commander of the National Guard Tenguiz Kitovani joins the anti-Gamsakhourdia camp. At the end of December 1991, they began the siege of Parliament, which was taken on 6 January 1992, the date of the coup d'état that led to President Gamsakhourdia's exile to his Caucasian neighbours. At that time, a State Council was formed and former leader of the Georgian Communist Party Eduard Shevardnadze was appointed as head of the Interim Council.*
>
> ***He continued the war in South Ossetia and, instead of reducing separatist conflicts, sent Georgian troops to Abkhazia to repress nationalists who were also moving towards secession. But Tbilisi faces armed opposition and logistical support from Russia.** In just over a year, the war is over and the separatists, after declaring their independence, carry out ethnic cleansing of the Georgians on their territory. **Following this defeat, Tbilisi is trying to get politically closer to Russia, which agrees to send it military aid to fight the new opponents led by Gamsakhurdia** who has established a government in exile in Zugdidi.*

I don't understand why it was the nationalists, lead by Gamsakhourdia, that were helped by Russia first before it was the government that was helped by Russia. Was it at the same time? That would be nonsense.

<sub>I am looking for recent resources on history of Georgia or at least of the Caucasus in French, if you have any ideas please let me know :)</sub>

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia%E2%80%93Russia_relations) on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: *I don't understand why it was the nationalists, lead by Gamsakhourdia, that were helped by Russia* In your translation it says the opposite. Shevarnadze was helped to fight already ousted Gamsahurdia

Comment: *Tbilisi is trying to get politically closer to* **Russia, which agrees to send it military aid to fight** *the new opponents led by* **Gamsakhurdia**

Comment: @user907860 *[head of the Interim Council Eduard Shevardnadze] sent Georgian troops to Abkhazia to repress nationalists who were also moving towards secession. But Tbilisi faces armed opposition and logistical support from Russia*. So this is why it seems to me that it was indeed was the nationalists, lead by Gamsakhourdia, that was helped by Russia first. 1. I don't understand why Russia would have helped the one then/and the other. 2. It is unclear if it helped opponents 3. I don't understand why Russia would have helped nationalists regarding its tradition of staelites states.

Comment: you seem to be confusing two different "nationalists". Russia *allegedly* supported nationalists in Abkhazia, who were "Abkhazian" nationalists. Gamsakhurdia was the leader of Georgian nationalists. When he was ousted by Shevarnadze, Russia *allegedly* provided support for Shevarndze to fight Georgian nationalists

Comment: In Abkhazia the Tbilisi government was facing Abkhazian nationalists, which were supported by Russia. At the time the Tbilisi government was controlled by Georgian nationalists, led by Gamsakhourdia, who was then the president of Georgia. You said, Shevarnadze was the head of Interim Council, I don't know such details, but he well could be in the government too, but wasn't the head of it. So at that time "Georgian nationalists" and "Tbilisi government" could be considered the same thing **and Russia wasn't supporting them**.

Comment: When Gamsakhourdia was ousted, so was the nationalist faction from the government in Tbilisi, so then Russia could start support Tbilisi government to fight ousted Georgian nationalist

Comment: I know next to nothing about Georgia, but re. your last sentence: Supporting both sides in a conflict is useful if you want both sides to weaken each other. Cf the US and the First Gulf War (the **real** First Gulf War).